# SPSS data restructuring

Tags: spss

I need to change my SPSS data restructuring from 
this

```
ID1:reading comprehension 1,reading comprehension 2 reading comprehension 3,
ID2:reading comprehension 1,reading comprehension 2 reading comprehension 3,
```

to

```
ID1 reading comprehension 1
ID1 reading comprehension 2
ID1 reading comprehension 3
```

this is the syntax I have tried:

```
SORT CASES BY ID PunkteT1 PunkteT2 PunkteT3 MW1 MW2 MW3 IMW1 IMW2 IMW3 Vorwissen_T1 Vorwissen_T2 
    Vorwissen_T3 Interesse_T1 Interesse_T2 Interesse_T3 UMW1 UMW2 UMW3.
CASESTOVARS
  /ID=ID
  /INDEX=PunkteT1 PunkteT2 PunkteT3 MW1 MW2 MW3 IMW1 IMW2 IMW3 Vorwissen_T1 Vorwissen_T2 
    Vorwissen_T3 Interesse_T1 Interesse_T2 Interesse_T3 UMW1 UMW2 UMW3
  /GROUPBY=VARIABLE.
```

It doesn't work out because of this warnings:

> In case 2, an invalid index value was determined. String index values
>   can not be empty. Numeric index values must not be negative integers.
>   The execution of this command has been stopped.

I already tried to solve this but without any success.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Kathrin

Comment: You want to use VARSTOCASES instead of CASESTOVARS. Something like `VARSTOCASES /MAKE ReadComp FROM ReadComp1 ReadComp2 ReadComp3 /MAKE MW FROM MW1 MW2 MW3 /INDEX Order.`

Comment: @andyW , that's the answer of course - why put in a comment?

Comment: I don´t get it donewarnings
Missing parentheses in the INDEX subcommand.
The execution of this command has been stopped.

Comment: @andyW 's command should have worked - I posted the same solution with  some explanation and better formatting - try to use that, hopefully it will work

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now are extra variables that you want to turn into cases, so the kind of restructure you need, as @andyW says, is `varstocases` and not `casestovars`.
The command will take each set of three variables and turn them into one variable over three cases instead:

```
varstocases 
  /make ReadComp FROM ReadComp1 ReadComp2 ReadComp3 
  /make PunkteT from PunkteT1 PunkteT2 PunkteT3
  /make MW from MW1 MW2 MW3 
  /make IMW from IMW1 IMW2 IMW3 
  /make Vorwissen_T from Vorwissen_T1 Vorwissen_T2 Vorwissen_T3
  /make Interesse_T from Interesse_T1 Interesse_T2 Interesse_T3
  /INDEX=OrigVarOrder.
```